# Bad cast exception on poco-library when I tried to cast Int64

Tags: c++, json, exception, casting, poco-libraries

I wrote some code for parse JSON string.
I got "Bad Cast Exception" sometimes.
In My JSON string *1. 2.* don't raise exception and *3. 4.* raise exception.

A difference between two group is that *1. 2.*'s BCodeW is in range long and *3. 4.*'s BCodeW is in range Int64.

**Why the casting raise the exception ?**

I wrote some guard code for Bad Cast Exception but I wanna know the reason of exception.

Thanks for reading.

---

my environment is below.

- g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
- poco-1.6.0 (using Poco::JSON)
- CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

---

My JSON string example below.

1. {"y":37.56376,"x":126.97287,"poiY":37.563686111111,"poiX":126.97302222222,"jibunY":37.563805555556,"jibunX":126.97285833333,**"BCodeW":1114016700**,"poi":"...","jibun":"..."}
2. {"y":37.59771,"x":127.041493,"poiY":37.597605555556,"poiX":127.041725,"jibunY":37.597547222222,"jibunX":127.04176666667,**"BCodeW":1129013600**,"poi":"...","jibun":"..."}
3. {"y":36.760035,"x":127.250362,"poiY":36.759905555556,"poiX":127.25036111111,"jibunY":36.760119444444,"jibunX":127.25040833333,**"BCodeW":4413125029**,"poi":"...","jibun":"..."}
4. {"y":36.129513,"x":128.34381,"poiY":36.128672222222,"poiX":128.34373888889,"jibunY":36.129738888889,"jibunX":128.34425833333,**"BCodeW":4719010200**,"poi":"...","jibun":"..."}

---

My Code is below.

```
bool CUBIUtils::ParseAddressResult( llong& _BCodeW, char* _szPOI, char* _szJibun, char* _szAPIResult )
{
  JSON::Parser parser;
  try
  {
    JSON::Object::Ptr _object = parser.parse(_szAPIResult).extract<JSON::Object::Ptr>();
    if ( NULL == _object)
    {
      formatlog( LOG_ERROR, "JSON parsing failed");
      return false;
    }

    formatlog( LOG_DEBUG, "CUBIUtils::%s(%d) AddrSrc: %s", __func__, __LINE__, _szAPIResult);

    _BCodeW = 0;
    try
    {
      _BCodeW = _object->get("BCodeW").extract<Int64>();
    }
    catch(exception &_e)
    {
      _BCodeW = _object->get("BCodeW").extract<int>();
    }

    strcpy(   _szPOI, _object->get("poi").extract<std::string>().c_str());
    strcpy( _szJibun, _object->get("jibun").extract<std::string>().c_str());
  }
  catch(exception &e)
  {
    formatlog( LOG_ERROR, "CUBIUtils::%s(%d) JSON parsing Exception. %s", __func__, __LINE__, e.what());
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

---

Var.h in Poco's source code says.

> ```
>   /// Invoke this method to perform a safe conversion.
>   ///
>   /// Example usage:
>   ///     Var any("42");
>   ///     int i = any.convert<int>();
>   ///
>   /// Throws a RangeException if the value does not fit
>   /// into the result variable.
>   /// Throws a NotImplementedException if conversion is
>   /// not available for the given type.
>   /// Throws InvalidAccessException if Var is empty.
> ```

---

**Below Code works.**

**use `convert<T>()` instead of `extract<T>()`**

Data type is different. **"i", "l"**

`extract` get data which are exactly match type.

```
_BCodeW = 0;
if ( _object->isNull("BCodeW"))
  cout << "BCodeW is NULL" << endl;
else
{
  Dynamic::Var _BCodeWVar = _object->get("BCodeW");
  cout << "Data Type is " << _BCodeWVar.type().name() << endl;

  _BCodeW = _BCodeWVar.convert<Int64>();
  cout << "BCodeW is " << _BCodeW << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not in the JSON parsing and/or data extraction. It is in the comparison line:

```
if (NULL == _object)
```

that line  will result in BadCastException being thrown.

The reason is because the `operator==` resolves to

```
inline bool operator == (const Poco::Int32& other, const Var& da)
```

and [conversion](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/Dynamic/Var.h#L1476) of `Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr` to `Poco::Int32`  throws.

Replace the offending line with

```
if (_object.isNull())
```

and all will be well.

Comment: I tried to find answer and I got some answer.

1. `if (_object.isNull())` what you mentioned is required
- if bcodew value is null then raise exception.



2. I have to use `convert<typename T>()` than `extract`